APScheduler scheduler.shutdown(wait=True) not waiting for background tasks to complete
I am creating 2 background schedulers, after the tasks on both the schedulers are started, I am calling scheduler.shutdown(wait=True) but it is not waiting for the tasks to complete, I got around this by having a while loop which check pending jobs using scheduler.get_jobs(), but reading the documentation it should not be required because shutdown(wait=True) is for this purpose, or did I read it wrong.
import time
import os
import random

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime,timezone,timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

some_data = None # task1() updates it and task2() reads it

def time_now():
    return datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone(ZoneInfo('localtime'))
    
def time_now_str():
    return time_now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

def random_int():
    return random.randint(10000000000, 99999999999)

def task1(taskid):
    global some_data
    os.system('/usr/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=10 count=10000 2> /dev/null') ## dummy task
    some_data =random_int()
    print(f'## Task1 ID: {taskid}, Generated some random data = {some_data}, '+time_now_str())
    return some_data

def task2(taskid):
    global some_data
    if some_data is not None:
        curr_data = some_data
        print(f'-- Task2 ID: {taskid}, STARTED task2 for data = {curr_data}: '+time_now_str())
        os.system('/usr/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=10 count=5000000 2> /dev/null') ## dummy task
        print(f'-- Task2 ID: {taskid}, DONE task2 for data = {curr_data}: '+time_now_str())
    else:
        print(f'-- Task2 ID: {taskid}, WARNING, no data yet, looks like task1() has not run yet, '+time_now_str())

        
## main()
 
task1_scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(executors={'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(1)}, job_defaults={'misfire_grace_time': 500, 'coalesce': False})
task2_scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(executors={'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(1)}, job_defaults={'misfire_grace_time': 500, 'coalesce': False})
        
start_time = time_now()

print('Start Time: '+start_time.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))

task1_tm = start_time
for idx, interval in enumerate( [1, 8, 14], start=1):
    task1_id = 'task1_id_'+str(idx)
    task1_tm += timedelta(seconds=interval)
    task1_scheduler.add_job(task1,'date',  run_date=task1_tm,  args=[task1_id], id=task1_id, max_instances=1)

task2_tm=start_time
for idx, interval in enumerate([0, 4,19,28], start=1):
    task2_id =  'task2_id_'+str(idx)
    task2_tm += timedelta(seconds=interval)
    task2_scheduler.add_job(task2,'date',  run_date=task2_tm, args=[task2_id], id =task2_id, max_instances=1)

task1_scheduler.start()
task2_scheduler.start()

# I should not need this
while len(task1_scheduler.get_jobs()) > 0 or len(task2_scheduler.get_jobs()) > 0:
    time.sleep(1)

task1_scheduler.shutdown(wait=True)
task2_scheduler.shutdown(wait=True)
    
print(f'Tasks completed: {time_now_str()}\n')


OS: Linux Mint 21.2
APScheduler: v3.10.4
Python: v3.10.12


there is very limited gain in the random_int() function that simply calls randint...

@D.L It was a quick copy paste from something else I wrote, so kept many things as it is.

Actually, the short answer is your tasks are to quick, so there is nothing to wait for:
The first task takes 0.011 s, and the second one takes 0.0001 s
Taking a closer look to your workflow I see following:

Your first task is starting with interval 1s based on following for idx, interval in enumerate([1, 8, 14], start=1):
The second one is starting with interval 0s for idx, interval in enumerate([0, 4, 19, 28], start=1)

So, in fact task 2 starts before task 1, but it doesn't have any data to read and your code is finishing.
More over most likely you mean task1_scheduler here:
task2_scheduler.add_job(task1,'date',  run_date=task1_tm,  args=[task1_id], id=task1_id, max_instances=1)
Anyway, it seems like you use this library not in the right way. Let me provide you an example just in case:
def get_jobs() -> list[dict[str, Any]]:
    """Get the list of prepared jobs."""

    return [
        {
            "id": "your_function_here_id",
            "func": your_function_here,
            "replace_existing": True,
            "trigger": CronTrigger(hour=23, minute=30, timezone=pytz.utc),
        },
        # More jobs to run
    ]


async def start_worker() -> None:
    """Start worker containing cron jobs."""
    
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(
        jobstores={"default": MemoryJobStore()},
        executors={"default": AsyncIOExecutor()},
        job_defaults={"coalesce": False, "max_instances": 1, "misfire_grace_time": 300},
        timezone="UTC",
    )

    for job in get_jobs():
        scheduler.add_job(**job)

    scheduler.print_jobs()
    scheduler.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start_worker())

You should better add try / finally with shutdown, but the idea is following. Hope it'll help!
